# How to capture real time weather data of points using OpenWeatherMap

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, weather, real-time, openweathermap-api

I want to set points on a map layer with autofilled data in some fields in the attribute table, which already works fine with date/time and username/observer.

Is there also a way to capture real time weather data every time a point is set on the layer? (E.g. temperature, humidity and sight)

I have access to an API Key of [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org/).

Comment: Do you have a data source?

Comment: Are you capturing your own data or using a weather api?

Comment: Yes I have a data source / api key (OpenWeatherMap).

Answer (score 6):

You could use a custom function such as:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import urllib.request
import urllib
import json

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def jsonfromurl(url, feature, parent):
    header = {"accept":"application/json"}
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    response_data = response.read()
    encoding = response.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(response_data.decode(encoding))
    #txt = json.dumps(data) #uncomment this line to receive data as string. also change next line to: return txt
    return data
```

This function will get a JSON-Response from a given URL.

Open the expression dialog, for example via field calculator, and go to the "Function Editor"-Tab:

[image]

Save and load the custom function. Then go back to the regular "Expression"-Tab. Here you can use the new function. Dont forget to insert your personal API-Key.

Here some usage examples:

**Get the "main"-content for your current location:**

```
map_get(
jsonfromurl('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' ||$y || '&lon=' || $x || '&appid=' || 'yourapikeyhere'),
'main')
```

[image]

**Get the temperature for `lat=35` and `lon=139`:**

```
map_get(
map_get(
jsonfromurl('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=' || 'yourapikeyhere'),
'main'),
'temp')
```

[image]

**Get the wind speed of the current location:**

```
map_get(
map_get(
jsonfromurl('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' ||$y || '&lon=' || $x || '&appid=' || 'yourapikeyhere'),
'wind'),
'speed')
```

[image]

If you want to get the current location, make sure your layer is in EPSG:4326 (or use `transform()`, e.g. `map_get(map_get(jsonfromurl('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' ||y(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) || '&lon=' || x(transform($geometry,layer_property(@layer,'crs'),'EPSG:4326')) || '&appid=' || 'yourapikeyhere'),'wind'),'speed')`).

If you need metric units from the response, just add `units=metric` to the url. For example:

```
map_get( map_get( jsonfromurl('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&lat=' ||$y || '&lon=' || $x || '&appid=' || 'yourapikeyhere'), 'main'), 'temp')
```

As you can see, you need to change `map_get()` and/or the URL depending on what you want to receive. Check out openweathermap API docs for details: https://openweathermap.org/current#geo or look at their example response, e.g.:

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":282.1,"feels_like":281.16,"temp_min":279.82,"temp_max":284.82,"pressure":1013,"humidity":76},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":1.95,"deg":63,"gust":2.92},"clouds":{"all":59},"dt":1617734050,"sys":{"type":3,"id":2019346,"country":"JP","sunrise":1617740571,"sunset":1617786549},"timezone":32400,"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji","cod":200}
```

If you enter this expression as default value in attributes form, it will be the standard-value for your field:

[image]

Example result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! With some fixed lat&long it works.  But if I type in the string for my current location, it shows me: Eval Error: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request (?)

Comment: WGS84 / Pseudo-Mercator

Comment: @Zess Make sure your layer is in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326). OpenWeatherMap only works with lat lon as far as I know. Alternatively you can use `transform()`. See my edit.

Comment: Ok. I noticed it works on any other layer in WGS84, just not on that specific one... I guess i just will build it new from scratch. Anyway, awesome it works! Last thing to do would be to convert the units into the metric system (units=metric?). I tried but failed.

Comment: at openweathermap.org I read: "Temperature is available in Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin units. For temperature in Fahrenheit use units=imperial
For temperature in Celsius use units=metric". It seems the default is Kelvin. I don't know how to change that, but I would need the data in the metric system.

Comment: Just add `units=metric` to the url. For example: `map_get(
map_get(
jsonfromurl('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&lat=' ||$y || '&lon=' || $x || '&appid=' || 'yourapikeyhere'),
'main'),
'temp')`. You can read this and more details up at https://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: Thanks! It is working in QGIS now, but not yet in the INPUT app. The app is the reason I wanted it that way, as I need to capture survey points in the field. Autofilled Date/time is working (default value in the attribute field: $now), username also (@mergin_username), with weather-data (e.g. temperature and windspeed) the fields are autofilled in QGIS but in the app the fields are empty. Any idea?

Comment: The app is called Input, similar to QField. Alright, I will open up a new question then, this solution here is helpful on its own already. Thanks mate, cheers!